# Combining JSON Files Without Overriding

Tags: python, json, merge

I have 2 JSON files that have the same names for keys. How can I combine these files without overriding in Python? I have tried both of these methods:

```
z = json_one.copy()
z.update(json_two)
```

^This overrides the data that is in json_one.

```
json_one['metros'].append(json_two['metros'])
```

^This is almost correct, but adds unnecessary square brackets.

Here are my 2 files:
json_one:

```
"metros" : [
    {
        "code" : "SCL" ,
        "name" : "Santiago" ,
        "country" : "CL" ,
        "continent" : "South America" ,
        "timezone" : -4 ,
        "coordinates" : {"S" : 33, "W" : 71} ,
        "population" : 6000000 ,
        "region" : 1
    } , {
        "code" : "LIM" ,
        "name" : "Lima" ,
        "country" : "PE" ,
        "continent" : "South America" ,
        "timezone" : -5 ,
        "coordinates" : {"S" : 12, "W" : 77} ,
        "population" : 9050000 ,
        "region" : 1
    } 
]
```

json_two:

```
"metros" : [
    {
       "code": "CMI",
       "name": "Champaign",  
       "country": "US", 
       "continent": "North America", 
       "timezone": -6, 
       "coordinates": {"W": 88, "N": 40},
       "population": 226000, 
       "region": 1
     }
]
```

The file I want created is this:

```
"metros" : [
    {
        "code" : "SCL" ,
        "name" : "Santiago" ,
        "country" : "CL" ,
        "continent" : "South America" ,
        "timezone" : -4 ,
        "coordinates" : {"S" : 33, "W" : 71} ,
        "population" : 6000000 ,
        "region" : 1
    } , {
        "code" : "LIM" ,
        "name" : "Lima" ,
        "country" : "PE" ,
        "continent" : "South America" ,
        "timezone" : -5 ,
        "coordinates" : {"S" : 12, "W" : 77} ,
        "population" : 9050000 ,
        "region" : 1
    } , {
        "code": "CMI",
        "name": "Champaign",  
        "country": "US", 
        "continent": "North America", 
        "timezone": -6, 
        "coordinates": {"W": 88, "N": 40},
        "population": 226000, 
        "region": 1
     }
]
```

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `list.extend()` method as follows:

```
json_one['metros'].extend(json_two['metros'])
```

The `l1.extend(l2)` method will extend `l1` by appending the items from `l2` as follows:

```
In [14]: l1 = [1, 2]

In [15]: l2 = [3, 4]

In [16]: l1.extend(l2)

In [17]: l1
Out[17]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The `l1.append(l2)` method will just append the object `l2` instead:

```
In [17]: l1
Out[17]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [18]: l1 = [1, 2]

In [19]: l2 = [3, 4]

In [20]: l1.append(l2)

In [21]: l1
Out[21]: [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

This is what created the 'unnecessary square brackets' in your attempt.